# ansible: I am not getting the entire error message for task

Tags: ansible

I have a ansible playbook for testing like this

```
---
- name: "test"
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: "list files"
      block:
        - name: "list files"
          command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
          register: output

      rescue:
        - script: test.py {{ output.msg }}
          args:
            executable: python3
```

and it will fail, I want to capture the error msg and send it to python script, test.py (for now, I just write the msg to a file

```py
import sys

with open("/tmp/workfile", "w") as f:
    f.write(sys.argv[1])
```

executing the playbook and I looked at the /tmp/workfile, I got

```
[Errno
```

Why am I not getting the entire error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the argument to your script.  Consider the following playbook:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    output:
      msg: This is a test.
  tasks:
    - script: test.py {{ output.msg }}
      args:
        executable: python3
      register: script1

    - script: test.py "{{ output.msg }}"
      args:
        executable: python3
      register: script2

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ script1.stdout }}"
          - "{{ script2.stdout }}"
```

Where `test.py` is simply:

```
import sys

print('argv[1]: ', sys.argv[1])
```

The final task outputs:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "argv[1]:  This\n",
        "argv[1]:  This is a test.\n"
    ]
}
```